# Is it possible to postpone the initialization of the test subject until the test case with EasyMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, easymock

Is it possible to initialize the object to test not on declaration but in each test case? I can't initialize the object on declaration because the parameters passed to the constructor are part of the test cases. I would need something as:

```
  @TestSubject
  private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

  @Mock
  private Collaborator mock;

  @Test
  public void test12() {
    classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(1, 2);
    replay(mock);
    Integer result = classUnderTest.work(3, 4);
    // Assertions
  }
```

But if I do the above, Easymock complains:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Have you forgotten to instantiate classUnderTest?
```

I've taken a look at [MockBuilder](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/internal/MockBuilder.html), but I don't see how it can help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

EasyMock does not support what you're asking for. Other testing libraries do/might support it, though. For example, using JMockit:

```
@Test
public void test12(
    @Injectable("1") int a, @Injectable("2") int b, @Tested ClassUnderTest cut
) {
    Integer result = cut.work(3, 4);
    // Assertions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can! There are two ways.

In the before:

```
private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

private Collaborator mock;

@Before
public void before() {
  classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(1, 2);
  EasyMockSupport.injectMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void test12() {
  classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(1, 2);
  replay(mock);
  Integer result = classUnderTest.work(3, 4);
  // Assertions
}
```

Or the good old way:

```
private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

private Collaborator mock;

@Test
public void test12() {
  mock = mock(Collaborator.class);
  replay(mock);

  classUnderTest.setCollaborator(mock);
  classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(1, 2);

  Integer result = classUnderTest.work(3, 4);
  // Assertions
}
```

Comment: Well, this is correct, but the question seems to assume use of `@TestSubject`. A future version of EasyMock could add support for "injectable" parameters declared in test methods, at least for JUnit 5 (which has a nice `ParameterResolver`).